# One PC, 4 iOS Devices, 4 iCloud Accounts?

Tags: itunes, ipod, ios, icloud

I have one PC running iTunes, my iPhone, and one iPod for each of three kids.

Ideally I would like the iPhone to use *my* iCloud account and each iPod to use an iCloud account specific to each kid.

[According to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4895):

> You can ... use one Apple ID for iCloud services and another Apple ID for store purchases

However, the method described

1. Enter the Apple ID you want to use for iCloud in Control Panel > Network and Internet > iCloud.
2. Enter the Apple ID you want to use for Store purchases (including iTunes in the Cloud and iTunes Match) in iTunes > iTunes Store.

would require that *all* iOS devices share the *same* iCloud account if they use iTunes on the same PC.

Short of having one PC per family member, is there a method to use different iCloud accounts on each iOS device?

Comment: have multiple users on the PC. each user gets their own iTunes library and you could link each user's iTunes install with a different iCloud account.

Comment: Can I still share a single Apple ID for purchases with that method?

Comment: @EricJ. - I would try and report back what you discover.